# How would I Pull Values of 1000+ Checkboxes in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am needing to pull the value of a checkbox (Form Control version) and insert it into a cell. I am aware of the method of Right-Clicking on a checkbox - Format Control - Control Tab - Cell Link, but for the spreadsheet I'm needing to do this for has 1000+ checkboxes. So performing that process would be an immense ordeal!

Is there a *value* a checkbox adheres to within an excel function? In other words, what variable would that checkbox respond to if I were to call that checkbox into a function?

i.e: `=IF(CheckBox3 = TRUE, "Complete", " ")` (I'm referring to the **CheckBox3** text)

Or is there an alternative method to obtaining this information? Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated! ([Photo of checkbox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJATy.jpg))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop the shapes collection and test whether it is a checkbox and apply your formula

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetValues()
    Dim shp As Shape, counter As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each shp In .Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoFormControl Then
                counter = counter + 1
                .Cells(counter, 1) = shp.NAME
                 If shp.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then .Cells(counter, 2) = "Complete"
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You may need to add an additional test, for example if they are called Check Box 1, Check Box 2 etc then something like:

```
If shp.Type = msoFormControl And InStr(shp.NAME, "Check Box") > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! So I've tried that code, and it prints each checkbox onto my spreadsheet; however, in the adjacent column it prints "Complete" whether or not the actual checkbox was checked or not. Did I miss a step somewhere?

Comment: Oh wow, I've been trying to figure out why True/False wasn't working for the past hour. Didn't think of trying 1 / 0 haha. Thank you!!